# Why is a JavaScript file not visible in debugger while it's obviously downloaded?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

I have an [OX](https://www.open-xchange.com/) application, which includes several JavaScript files. Those files are listed within the network panel (with status code 200) of the different DevTools - Firebug, Firefox DevTools and Chrome DevTools - and there is no error within the console, but they are not listed inside their debugger panels.
Though the code within the files **is** executed.

All files are loaded from the same server, so there is no cross-site scripting problem.

I expect all JavaScript sources, that can be parsed without errors to be available within the debugger.

So I wonder, what are the reasons that an executed JavaScript source is not shown within the debugger panel?

Comment: Maybe because there is no bug? I mean, what's your problem? Why would you find your files on the debugger?

Comment: With "debugger" I mean the panels where you can set breakpoints and step through your code. In the Chrome DevTools it is called [*Sources*](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging), in the Firefox DevTools [*Debugger*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger) and in Firebug it's called [*Script*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel). There **is** a bug I want to investigate.

Comment: Place a `debugger` statement in the file and see if it gets hit

Comment: Can you provide a site where this problem reproduces? It is extremely difficult to debug things like this that are working normally for many without a reproduction testcase.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the tip! This helped to realize that the file is included as dynamic script via `eval()`. I.e. it is not listed under its original name but has a random name.

Comment: @Garbee The page is a company internal page and I am not allowed to publicate its contents. Though this application is based on [OX](https://www.open-xchange.com/), which obviously includes all additional JavaScript files dynamically via `eval()`.